# At what point is the R-tree created?

Tags: postgis, spatial-database, rtree

**Whats going on:** I am working with postGIS and spatial datas. I am having trouble to fully understand the `R-tree` algorithm.

**Example query:** *In which town is point P located?*

**My understanding so far is:**
Each polygon has a `boundingBox`, this `boundingBox` has an idex. These `boundingBoxes` are then merged into another larger `boundingBox` which also has an idex. Continuing the process creates the `R-tree`. With the help of the `R-tree` the query is much faster. But ...

**My question** is at what point are these indexes created? 
Does the R-tree exists per se? 
Or is the `R-tree` created on the run time when I start a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a spatial index.

```
Create index idx_mytable_geom ON my_table USING gist(geom);
```

Then it is often a good idea to run

```
ANALYZE mytable;
```